# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress with Cert Manager and letsencrypt does not allow wildcarts in domain names

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, lets-encrypt, kubeadm, cert-manager

I have a self-hosted Kubernetes cluster with an Nginx Ingress. Cert-manager is also running on the cluster, with which I try to get valid SSL certificates using Letsencrypt. It all works and I get a valid certificate for example.com, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or app1.example.com, but not for a general wildcard *.example.com. If I try in any way to enter a wildcard in my ingress under sec.tls.hosts, no certificate is generated for me.
I get the output for

`kubectl get certificate`

```
NAME              READY   SECRET            AGE
tls-test-cert     False   tls-electi-cert   20h
```

`kubectl get CertificateRequest`

```
NAME                    APPROVED   DENIED   READY   ISSUER                REQUESTOR                                         AGE
tls-test-cert-8jw75     True                False   letsencrypt-staging   system:serviceaccount:cert-manager:cert-manager   18m
```

`kubectl describe CertificateRequest`

```
[...]
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2022-02-27T13:54:38Z
    Message:               Certificate request has been approved by cert-manager.io
    Reason:                cert-manager.io
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Approved
    Last Transition Time:  2022-02-27T13:54:38Z
    Message:               Waiting on certificate issuance from order gateway/tls-test-cert-8jw75-1425588341: "pending"
    Reason:                Pending
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:
  Type    Reason           Age   From          Message
  ----    ------           ----  ----          -------
  Normal  cert-manager.io  18m   cert-manager  Certificate request has been approved by cert-manager.io
  Normal  OrderCreated     18m   cert-manager  Created Order resource gateway/tls-test-cert-8jw75-1425588341
  Normal  OrderPending     18m   cert-manager  Waiting on certificate issuance from order gateway/tls-test-cert-8jw75-1425588341: ""
```

My Nginx Ingress: (I swapped my domain to example.com for this post)

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-management
  namespace: gateway
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - secretName: tls-test-cert
    hosts:
      - example.com
      - '*.example.com'
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: test-gateway
                port:
                  number: 80
    - host: '*.example.com'
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: test-gateway
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Issuer: (I've redacted my email here)

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: *******
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
```

My reverse proxy (test-gateway) definitely works and forwards all subdomains to my website.
Thanks in advance for any ideas as to what might be causing this.

Comment: Hi TaLeDa welcome to SF. To the best of my knowledge, [one cannot issue wildcard certs using http01 verifier](https://cert-manager.io/docs/faq/sync-secrets/#serving-a-wildcard-to-ingress-resources-in-different-namespaces-default-ssl-certificate) (since it would require unlimited http requests to proved all the `*` hosts). You'll be happier requesting a [`wildcard: true`](https://cert-manager.io/docs/reference/api-docs/#acme.cert-manager.io/v1.Challenge) cert and and then just attaching it to your Ingress. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. Have a nice day.

Comment: Then please [add and accept your own answer](https://serverfault.com/help/self-answer), so others can benefit from your experience -- that's the whole point of this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I was able to solve my problem:

Basically, I had to find a new approach because no wild card certificate can be issued with http01.
(see here: https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/)
After a little research I came to the conclusion that it makes the most sense to use a dns01 solver.
Documentation can be found here:
https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/

Since the configuration of the dns01 depends heavily on your DNS provider, I will not publish my solution here, but a useful configuration can easily be found with the documentation.